# How to add ASP.NET Core Identity to a project that already has a database and it's using ado.net, NOT EF Core

Tags: asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I have a project that's been recently re-written using ASP.NET Core 2.0.

It already has a database and the access layer was build using ADO.NET.

The only part of the application where I've managed to convinced my team to use EF Core is the user management module (mostly because all the goodies Identity provides out of the box)

Here's a list of the steps I followed:

1) Since I need to add two properties to the default implementation of User, I created a new class(that for this example I'm going to call **BlogUser**) which derives from **IdentityUser** :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace Core.DomainEntities
    {
        public class BlogUser : IdentityUser
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }


            //This is neccesary due to some changes in the new version of Identity
            //For more details see the section "Add IdentityUser POCO Navigation Properties" in :
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x 


            public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>> Roles { get; } = new List<IdentityUserRole<string>>();

            public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<string>> Claims { get; } = new List<IdentityUserClaim<string>>();

            public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<string>> Logins { get; } = new List<IdentityUserLogin<string>>();

        }
    }
```

2) Because I needed to use the **Claims** navigation property of **IdentityRole** and in the new version of Identity **Claims** is not part of it by default, I had to also extend this class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Core.DomainEntities
{
    public class BlogUserRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public BlogUserRole()
        {

        }

        public BlogUserRole(string roleName) : base(roleName)
        {

        }
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityRoleClaim<string>> Claims { get; } = new List<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>();
    }
}
```

3) Creating the DbContext class for identity:

```
using Core.DomainEntities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Infrastructure
{
    public class BloggerIdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<BlogUser>
    {       

        public BloggerIdentityContext(DbContextOptions options)
          : base(options)
        {            
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            //This is neccesary due to some changes in the version of Identity
            //For more details see the section "Add IdentityUser POCO Navigation Properties" in :
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x 

            builder.Entity<BlogUser>()
               .HasMany(e => e.Claims)
               .WithOne()
               .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
               .IsRequired()
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<BlogUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Roles)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<BlogUserRole>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.RoleId)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
}
```

4) Having all those classes in place all that remains is to setup Identity in the **StartUp** class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //... other configuration
    var connectionString = Configuration["connectionStrings:bloggerDBConnectionString"];

    services.AddDbContext<BloggerIdentityContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

    services.AddIdentity<BlogUser, BlogUserRole>(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<BloggerIdentityContext>();


}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, BloggerIdentityInitializer identitySeeder)
{
    //...some other configuration
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc();

}
```

With all the configuration been taken care of, I thought that it would only be a matter of **adding** a new migration, to then update the database with it, but all I get is this error when I try to **add the migration**:

> An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class
>   'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
>   One or more errors occurred. (Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.)
>
> Unable to create an object of type 'BloggerIdentityContext'. Add an
>   implementation of
>   'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project,
>   or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional
>   patterns supported at design time.

To be honest I have absolutely no idea where this *"Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'"* error is coming from or what might be causing it, so if someone could give me hand I'd be more than grateful.

Comment: Did you actually run a migration against the database? Identity depends on a number of tables, including `AspNetUsers` (the custom name it assigns to the table that stores users by default). Obviously, you're going to get errors like this if that table does not exist. Unlike EF, EF Core can actually run migrations on an existing database, without effecting the rest of that database, so you really shouldn't have any issues there. However, if you prefer, you can simply add the tables manually (just let Identity generate them in a new database and then copy those over to your existing database).

Comment: I don't think I get what you mean by "Did you actually run a migration against the database?" For my `BloggerIdentityContext` I'm using the same connection string I used for the rest of the project, if that's what you're asking. Also, isn't the `AspNetUsers` table supposed to be automatically created by `Identity`, along with the other 6 tables, when I add a migration?